# Is it possible for a maven reactor project to include another reactor sub-project as module?

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

Let's say there is a reactor project **myproject** with modules:

```
<modules>
  <module>parent</module>
  <module>core</module>
  <module>ui</module>
  <module>config</module>
</modules>
```

There is another reactor sub-project **integration-tests** inside **myproject**.

```
<modules>
  <module>admin</module>
  <module>base</module>
  <module>rest</module>
</modules>
```

So, the hierarchy is as:

```
myproject
|_ pom.xml
|_ parent
|_ core
|_ ui
|_ config
|_ integration-tests
      |_ admin
      |_ base
      |_ rest
```

Now, I want to build **integration-tests** modules along with **myproject** modules. One way is to append modules of **integration-tests** to **myproject** modules list.

But is it possible to write:

```
<modules>
  <module>parent</module>
  <module>core</module>
  <module>ui</module>
  <module>config</module>
  <module>integration-tests</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: make a pom file in `integration-tests`and put there list of modules `admin`, `base`, `rest` in it...If you build from root `myproject` all modules will be built based on their dependencies...reactor order....Apart from that looks wrong having a parent folder in under myproject...why not using the pom.xml in `myproject` as parent for other modules?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call this a **reactor project** (though, of course, technically spoken it is processed by the reactor)? The official term, however, is:

> #### [Aggregation (or Multi-Module)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)

> #### [3.6.2. Multi-module ...](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit)

Yes, it is possible. It's no problem for Maven at all.

But, if you use Eclipse as your IDE it can't handle nested projects too well. If you, for instance, select the `admin` project to create a new *Class* therein the creation dialog offers `myproject/src/main/java` as *Source folder*, so you have to adapt this every time accordingly. The *Build Paths* aren't display *Flat* either, if you selected this in the view's *Package Presentation.*

However, you can solve this:

- Create `myproject` and every *Maven Module* below.
- Delete `myproject` from Eclipse's workspace. Leave *Delete project contents on disk* unchecked!
- *Import* → *Existing Maven Projects:* `myproject` and all below.

Comment: The assumption of not handling nested modules not well is only partially true for old versions of Eclipse...starting with Neon there is a full hierarchical view in there (earlier versions have flatten the view but worked well with it)...so no problem. Also importing the whole project from root of such multi level multi module projects works without any issue...

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried it with Neon.3 yesterday and it behaved as described. Maybe I did not perform the proper steps in the proper sequence. Does this really deserve a downvote? Isn't your last sentence exactly what I mentioned as solution? What's the name of this hierarchical view? In Project Explorer it's as I described: The module projects are visible in **myproject** but just as general folders. No flat display. No overlay icons on them. No virtual library folders in them. Right-clicking and selecting _Configure Build Path_ on any of them shows the Build Path of the topmost **myproject**.

Comment: How have you imported them into Neon? Have you M2E installed ? Which version of it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I did not import them initially. I created them from scratch: The main **myproject** with _New_ → _Maven Project_, the projects below with _New_ → _Maven Module_ and also by C&P and adapting the POMs accordingly. Then I deleted them from wkspc and re-imported them, so that they appear as projects on the same level in the Project/Package Explorer View. It's the M2E that comes with Neon.3 JEE. I use v3.3.9 as external, not the embedded. I did an update recently. None were found for any feature/plugin.

Comment: Added a short video on [Youtube|(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJld3-RpBlg&t=160s) where you can take a look...(no audio)...

Comment: @khmarbaise That idea is great, but, unfortunately, with the maximal 480p resolution it's nearly impossible to recognize anything in the Eclipse views and dialogs (even on a 24" in fullscreen). And...there IS audio.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can import hierarchical oriented project very well.

You can see here an import of an hierarchical project.
[image: Import an hierarchical project into Eclipse]

The only thing you need to be aware of is to configure Eclipse to show it that way which can be done via:

[image: Configure to view hierarchical projects]

If you have configured it that way now you can view it in the projects view:

[image: hierarchical project view in Eclipse]